# What's the ideal module for playing and pausing audio in Python?

Tags: python, audio

I had previously considered using the 'playsound' module but found out it only plays audio, it can't pause it.

Are there any recommendations on modules I can use?

Comment: This is quite opinion based. StackOverflow is best suited to specific, well defined problems, demonstrated in a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Take a look at the [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Wiki for more info.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It depends on your needs. Check this page: https://wiki.python.org/moin/Audio

I used simpleaudio recently and it is extremely easy to use, but limited (and while it can stop playing sounds, does not have pausing by default).